# Sending a merge request through TFS 2008

Tags: branching-and-merging

I am wondering if TFS 2008 is capable of sending an automatic notification to a developer when a merge request for a specific bug, change request, etc is made?

Any suggestions?
Thanks,

nino11

Answer (score 0):

[TFS Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en) is the most detailed you can be with project alerts.

You cannot however send a notification when simply the request was made.  You can however send a notification as soon as a merge takes place (IE after it completes).  You can use the "Check in to specific folder" type of project alert.

I would install TFS Power Tools and take a look at all the features it has.  If its not there- you can't do it- at least not to my knowledge in TFS 2008.

Comment: I just found out we have tfs power tools so i'm going to check it out. Thanks for your response

Comment: No problem, plz make it as the answer for future users if it works out for you :)